# Implementing multiple identifiers for routing resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the scenario. Suppose each user account in my rails application have an unique user handles on top of their assigned ids, how might I modify the routes (or otherwise) such that

```
/users/1
/users/johnsmith
```

Would both show the user who has id `1` and user handle `'johnsmith'`?

I'm currently implementing it as follows by having a get_user method in my users controller which I call prior to the controller actions:

```
def get_user  
  identifier = params[:id]
  if identifier.to_i.to_s == identifier   # if numeric id
    @user = User.find(identifier)
  else  # else hande
    @user =  User.find_by(handle: identifier)
  end
end
```

Is there a more elegant solution to go about doing this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), it's exactly what you need.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'

$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :handle, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end

$ rails c
$ User.find_each(&:save)
```

This will replace all the references to `:id` in both your `routes` and model lookups, so you'll be able to use:

```
<%= link_to @user.handle, @user %>
```

... and it will show the user's handle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that i might work for your situation. in your routes you could create a route like this: `get '/user/:id_or_handle', controller: 'users', action: 'action', as: 'user_page'` as: creates a path `user_page_path`where you can pass in user object or `current_user` if you store user to [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session), like this `user_page_path(user.id or user.username)` then you can manipulate :id_or_handle